# C# Error: does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, list, class, listbox

I'm quite new to C# and i don't understand what i'm doing wrong, here is my code:

```
public class Client
        {

            public int Code { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Phone { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }

            public Client (int code, string name, int phone, string email)
            {
                Code = code;
                Name = name;
                Phone = phone;
                Email = email;

            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
            return string.Format("Code {0} | Name: {1} | Phone: {2} | Email{3}", Code, Name, Phone, Email);
            }

        }
        public frm_cadastro()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public List<Client> clieList = new List<Client>();

        private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            clieList.Add(new Client() //This is where the error is
            {
                Code = Convert.ToInt32(txt_cod.Text),
                Name = txt_name.Text,
                Phone = Convert.ToInt32(txt_phone.Text),
                Email = txt_email.Text,
            });
```

This code originated from a previous question, where i asked how could i load my list data into my text boxes.

Comment: Your Client class need 4 parameters but you  want to create it with `new Client()` Try `new Client(Convert.ToInt32(txt_cod.Text, txt_name.Text ........)` Reading a few docs about c# may help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
clieList.Add(new Client() //This is where the error is
{
    Code = Convert.ToInt32(txt_cod.Text),
    Name = txt_name.Text,
    Phone = Convert.ToInt32(txt_phone.Text),
    Email = txt_email.Text,
});
```

This is not constructor call you're looking for. It's parameterless constructor call + property initialization syntax. It doesn't work, because you class doesn't have parameterless constructor defined.

What you're looking for is:

```
clieList.Add(new Client(Convert.ToInt32(txt_cod.Text),
                       txt_name.Text,
                       Convert.ToInt32(txt_phone.Text),
                       txt_email.Text));
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this.

```
 clieList.Add(new Client() //This is where the error is
            {
                Code = Convert.ToInt32(txt_cod.Text),
                Name = txt_name.Text,
                Phone = Convert.ToInt32(txt_phone.Text),
                Email = txt_email.Text,
            });
```

To this

```
 clieList.Add(new Client(Convert.ToInt32(txt_cod.Text),txt_name.Text,Convert.ToInt32(txt_phone.Text),txt_email.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to create an instance of Client without sending any arguments to the constructor.

The constructor:

```
public Client (int code, string name, int phone, string email)
```

Solution 1: Supply the constructor arguments:

```
private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            clieList.Add(new Client(Convert.ToInt32(txt_cod.Text), txt_name.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txt_phone.Text), Email = txt_email.Text,
```

Solution 2: Add a parameterless constructor:

```
public Client()
```

And call as before:

```
private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            clieList.Add(new Client() //This is where the error is
            {
                Code = Convert.ToInt32(txt_cod.Text),
                Name = txt_name.Text,
                Phone = Convert.ToInt32(txt_phone.Text),
                Email = txt_email.Text,
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty much what the error says. The `Client` class has no default (ie parameterless) constructor.

This:

```
new Client
{
    Code = Convert.ToInt32(txt_cod.Text),
    Name = txt_name.Text,
    Phone = Convert.ToInt32(txt_phone.Text),
    Email = txt_email.Text,
}
```

Is syntactic sugar for this:

```
var client = new Client();
client.Code = Convert.ToInt32(txt_cod.Text);
client.Name = txt_name.Text;
client.Phone = Convert.ToInt32(txt_phone.Text);
client.Email = txt_email.Text;
```

The `new Client()` call is an object instantiation using the default constructor, which does not exist since you defined a custom constructor: if you define no constructor in your class, then the compiler will insert an implicit default constructor, but since you defined a custom one, no default constructor will be implicitly defined.

You have to do this instead:

```
new Client(Convert.ToInt32(txt_cod.Text),
           txt_name.Text,
           Convert.ToInt32(txt_phone.Text),
           txt_email.Text)
```

Or define a default constructor in the `Client` class:

```
public Client()
{
}
```